# JavaFX launch failed : javafx.fxml.LoadException:

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, fxml

I have an issue with the `FXMLLoader` which is looking recurrent but I can't fix it despite all the things I read here.
Here is my error code :

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
    /C:/Users/mouna/Desktop/DatabaseProject/databaseProject/bin/main/login.fxml:13

    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:932)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:982)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:229)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:754)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2808)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2634)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3323)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3280)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3249)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3222)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3199)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3192)
    at databaseProject/main.Main.start(Main.java:17)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:474)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:447)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:446)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: LoginController.java
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:930)
    ... 22 more
```

People are saying this issue is due to a wrong pathfile and I try to do it as simple as possible :

[path structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0WrD.png)

and my main class code

```
package main;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;

public class LoginController {

    @FXML
    private Button exitButton;

    public void exitButtonOnAction(ActionEvent event) {
        Stage stage = (Stage) exitButton.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.close();
    }
}
```

login.fxml code

```
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="520.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/16" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="LoginController.java">
```

Thank you if you have a specific solution because I am running out of idea.

Answer (score 1):

This part of the stack trace you posted indicates the problem cause.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: LoginController.java
```

`FXMLLoader` is looking for a class named `java` in package `LoginController`.

Change this part of your `login.fxml` file

```
fx:controller="LoginController.java"
```

to this

```
fx:controller="main.LoginController"
```

Now `FXMLLoader` will look for a class named `LoginController` in package `main`.

Comment: Thank you very much it works ! Still have an issue with images but I'll make it !